# Image resize with window, based on set pixel margins?

Tags: html, css, image, resize, margins

I'm trying to get an image centered on the screen, and I want it to stretch horizontally.
The trick here is that I need set margins. Lets use 200px as an example.

The image needs to stretch horizontally (and possibly scale proportionally) to maintain those margins no matter the windows size.

I can center it, and I can stretch it, but I can't do both at once for some reason.

Also, this needs to be CSS only! No JS.

**Any help is greatly appreciated! :D**

P.S. I've seen ton of questions about scaling images with the window size, and this is not the same thing. I need set margins, in pixels, that stay constant, while the image between them stretches horizontally.

Comment: CSS does not support dynamic margins. You are most likely going to have to use Javascript to achieve this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp
ummmmmm, no?

Comment: *Dynamic* meaning you can't change the margin in response to changes in the window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two divs, the outer with the set margins, the inner with width set to 100%:

http://jsfiddle.net/tqmrY/4/

```
<div id="holder">
    <div></div>
</div>​

#holder {
    background: #333;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 100px;
}
#holder div {
        width: 100%;

}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

I put a container around my image which would preserve the margins. As the window's width changes, the margin stays intact - only the width of the `.container` is changed. By setting the width of the image within the container to equal 100%, the entire image would be scaled (proportionally) based on the width of the container:

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 200px;
    background: red;
}

.container img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.aviationnews.eu/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Olympic-Rings.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by putting your image in a div and then putting padding on the div.

You would set your img to have a width of 100% and auto height, and then put padding on the containing div.

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/uJnmf/